# press key inside an input box

Tags: javascript, key-events

I am filling up a login form using

```
     document.getElementById('i0116').value = email;
     document.getElementById('i0118').value = password;
     document.getElementById('idSIButton9').click();
```

Now the problem starts when form is identifying that the value is not filled by any key event, I mean the placeholders remains there even if I fill the form and on submit it says fields are empty.

I was trying to fix it by firing a keypress event on input box before I fill the value. but I am not able to do it.
I tried :

```
var target = document.getElementById('email');
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");

evt.initEvent("keypress", true, true);

evt.view = window;
evt.altKey = false;
evt.ctrlKey = false;
evt.shiftKey = false;
evt.metaKey = false;
evt.keyCode = 0;
evt.charCode = 'a';

target.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

also instead of "Events" I tried **"UIEVENTS"** and **"KEYEVENTS"** none of them helped , I am using chrome browser.

Comment: for what did I got the negative votes ?  :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue was resolved using:

```
var element = document.getElementById('idTxtBx_SAOTCC_OTC');    
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

It was knockout js, because of which just setting the value of element was not working.so I was trying to keypress.
chanage event triggers "textInput" for knockoutjs, Instead of just setting .value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the hang of what you really are seeking to achieve. You can clear off the placeholder value `onClick()` and restore the placeholder value using `onBlur()`, something like the following

```js
function clearPlaceholder(id){
      document.getElementById(id).placeholder = "";
  };

function restorePlaceHolder(id, placeHolderText){
      document.getElementById(id).placeholder = placeHolderText;
  };
```

```html
<input id="10116" placeholder="email" onClick="clearPlaceholder('10116')" onBlur="restorePlaceHolder('10116','email')">
<input id="10118" placeholder="password" onClick="clearPlaceholder('10118')" onBlur="restorePlaceHolder('10118','password')">
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry @kailas it didn't work with setting placeholders :(

Comment: Could you try now?

Comment: Thanks @kailas for your effort but I don't need to hide placeholders , I want to fill the value of input box using keypress event (like we generally directly set the value using element.value = "email"), I don't want to use that but use keypress to fill the inputbox value ,and placeholders automatically hides if we press a key in an input box , so no need for a different function for it.